# AngularJS Drag and Drop event listner not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

By studying [article](https://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html) i am trying to develop my drag and drop but it is not working. Here is My [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZdzVo).

The issue i am facing is my events are not firing. can anyone help me for this?
when i move swipe me button to any shape i want to invoke alert which is mentioned in controller dd. If swipe me button is dropped on red triangle i am expecting that i will alert dropped on red and same as for other shapes

```
 el.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    debugger;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    this.classList.remove('over');

    var item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
    this.appendChild(item);

    scope.$apply('drop()');

    return false;
  }, false);
```

Thanks,

Comment: When you do what, what happens?

Comment: when i move swipe me button to any shape i want to invoke alert which is mentioned in controller dd. If swipe me button is dropped on red triangle i am expecting that i will alert dropped on red and same as for other shapes

Comment: For me, in the latest Chrome on Windows 7, it works for the bottom blue region but not for the others. That should be a good place to start.

Comment: I can also get it to work in red and green but it's a very narrow region that I have to drop in. I think your drag and drop is working but somewhere in your defining of where it can be dropped there's an issue.

Comment: [Here's a picture of what I'm seeing.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/phYXU.png) The blue rectangle is the div that houses your bottom triangle. If I drag the circle over the left or right triangle but I'm still inside that blue region, it won't drop. If you drag the circle to either triangle but your above that region, you'll be able to successfully drop and fire the correct event.

Comment: if you debug you find droppable directive events  not working.

Comment: it is responsive design. whereas drag button is not responsive which i will do later. if you debug by opening console in undock into separate mode you will see swap me button not working but drop events are not firing

Comment: I'm hitting the debugger statements and seeing the correct alert() dialogs for every triangle. But I've described that there are very particular regions you have to drop in. Whether the developer tools are docked or a free floating window, I get it to work either way. The problem is your Blue Triangle div.

Comment: i have this all in html file. and in i have opened browser console as separate window and to me it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely a CSS issue. The blue triangle is covering the majority of the red and green ones and is higher in the DOM. I see the red and green triangles alert fine IF I drop into the uncovered portions. The blue rectangle you see highlighted is the DOM space the blue triangle is occupying, which is it's clickable area.

[image]

Comment: In your link to the two boxes, the left bin only has a small space available to register events because the right bin is covering most of it. It's actually the exact same situation. Both codepen examples work, and in both examples one element is covering most of the other elements.